# Replacing column selection with ">" removes code lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have several lines of property definitions, e.g.:

```
public InputProp<string CsProtocol { private get; set; }
public InputProp<string CsHost { private get; set; }
public InputProp<string CsPort { private get; set; }
public InputProp<string CsService { private get; set; }
```

Now I want to insert a `>` after the `string`s.
So I use the column selection (*Alt+DrawLeftMouse*) to select column after *string* in all lines. After that I press `>` and expect that `>` will be inserted after `string`s of all lines.
But unfortunatily the first lines are removed and `>` is inserted only to the last line.
What is so special with `>`? It works with other characters.

Is there a workaround or fix to insert `>` in column selections?

Comment: in my Visual Studio it works, check your selection rectangle

Comment: You could ude find and replace

Comment: @Tigran Which VS version do you have? I have VS 2010 Premium 10.0.20319.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not select the lines and use the find and replace function ?

- find: `InputProp<string` (dont forget the space after string)
- replace: `InputProp<string>`

Comment: what you would find for, to replace after?

Comment: Or more like Find: "InputProp<string C" - Replace: "InputProp<string> C"

Comment: better find `InputProp<string ` with a space at the end

Comment: @Uriel_SVK yes right. i updated my answer to make it more clear. It was not visible in the answer.